# IE7 and display block on HTML strict

Tags: xhtml, internet-explorer-7, block, strict

I'm having difficulties with an image taking extra space although it is set to display:block in css. This is only happening on IE7. The problem is solved when I remove all spaces between the tags in the HTML code, but this is not a suitable solution.

I have heard of some IE7 hacks like setting a fixed width/height and the following css:

```
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

But this didn't work for me (maybe because I am using XHTML strict).

The page I am working on is the following: http://www.morgana.nl/slaaptest/afspraak.html

The top image is an image that is set as display: block and a div with blue background follows.

Link to image: http://www.morgana.nl/temp/ie7-display-block.png

Hoping for some useful help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using XHTML, I'm assuming you want your markup to be semantic. So technically `/siteimages/forms/bottom.jpg` and `/siteimages/forms/top.jpg` aren't images that have any meaning, compared to say the photo of the people. 
Since it's just a decoration, so why not style them using `background` CSS property and apply them to your `<div>` containers to achieve the same effect?

Eg.

```
.roundedTopBar {
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: transparent url('/siteimages/forms/top.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.roundedBottomBar {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: transparent url('/siteimages/forms/bottom.jpg') 0 100% no-repeat;
}

<div class="half2 roundedTopBar">
   <div class="roundedBottomBar">
      <div class="formsContainer">
        ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Added:** If you did want to know how accomplish what your question originally asked for, the solution is to not use `display: inline-block` because IE 7 mucks it up. Use `float: left; clear: both; display: block;` and make sure you clear your floats in the parent container.

Eg. This is the snippet from your website, I added `newCSS` to namespace the new stuff I added, you can use whatever selector names you'd think suitable

CSS:

```
.newCSS .clearFloat{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}
.newCSS .inlineBlock {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="half2 clearFloat newCSS">
    <img src="http://www.morgana.nl/siteimages/forms/top.jpg" width="441"
    height="12" class="block inlineBlock" alt=""/>
    <div class="formsContainer block inlineBlock">
        <div class="formsInnerContainer" style="height:474px">
        form was here
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.morgana.nl/siteimages/forms/bottom.jpg" class="block inlineBlock" alt=""/>
</div>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/c34ny/

If you're viewing on IE7 (it doesn't like jsFiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/c34ny/embedded/result/

Comment: You are very right. It's better to not use foreground images for design purposes because they have no non-technical meaning. If i'm right images are naturally inline elements and this is why display:block isn't honored in IE7.

But when I do need to use a foreground image, why does the above workaround not work in IE7? I suppose it's because i'm using a strict document type (not tested yet)...

Comment: You are the best. Thanks for your help. One related question. I started using spacer images for layout purposes because when using divs i would get a extremely big css file because I can't set div width and height in inline css while being semantic. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @Hans you don't have to use spacer images. Why not create generic CSS class names, eg: `spacer_horizontal { div: block; padding-bottom: 10px; }` and so forth....that way you can apply these generic *spacer* class names on anything you'd like